# number theory problem. is there no solution for $x^2 + 2y^2 = 23^2 \pmod{23}$?

Tags: number-theory

Show that the following equation has no
positive solution except $(x, y) = (23, 0):  x^2 + 2y^2 = 23^2$

I want to know the detailed procedure

i guess that in $\mod 23, x^2$ can be some cycle.

Comment: Please do write mathematics writing correctly abiding by the easy directions  in the site.

Comment: As you are doing $\pmod{23}$ why write $=23^3$, why not just write $=0^2$?

Comment: Why in the title of the question there is that $\pmod{23}$, while in the body of the question there isn't? The modular one has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Are you familiar with the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$? Do you know it is a ring of (algebraic) integers? Do you know what is the norm of elements of this ring?

Comment: Anyway, the simplest proof is an exhaustive search of the solutions for $0 \le x,y \le 23$. This requires some time, but it is accessible to anybody.

Comment: user329827 is going to ask us to solve all his number theory exercices (3 or 4 asked in less than one hour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $23$ divides $y$, then it divides $x$ as well.
Writing $x=23u$ and $y=23v$, we get
$$
u^2+2v^2=1
$$
which implies $u=\pm 1$ and $v=0$ and $x=\pm 23$ and $y=0$.

If $23$ does not divide $y$, then $x^2 \equiv -2y^2 \bmod 23$ and $(xz)^2 \equiv -2 \bmod 23$, where $yz \equiv 1 \bmod 23$.

This means that $-2$ is a quadratic residue mod $23$. Let's check [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion):
$$
(-2)^{\frac{23-1}{2}} = (-2)^{11} = - 2048 \equiv -1 
\bmod 23
$$
and so $-2$ is *not* a quadratic residue mod $23$.